# Gallery with center image zoomedin in android

Tags: android

I am using gallery for displaying images by scrolling through it. I have used `getChildStaticTransformation(View child,Transformation t)` method for applying transformations to each child that is to each of the images.

But now I want to use buttons to scroll through images. So I am calling the method `getChildStaticTransformation` from the `onTouch` event of button. But the images are not moving.

The code is as follows:-

In the constructor of the class i have used,

```
    this.setStaticTransformationsEnabled(true);
```

so the below method is getting fired all by itself when i scroll the screen.But i want to use the method on button click now.I have tried calling this method inside button click explicitly but it is not working.

```
protected boolean getChildStaticTransformation(View child, Transformation t) {

    final int childCenter = getCenterOfView(child);
    final int childWidth = child.getWidth();
    int rotationAngle = 0;

    t.clear();
    t.setTransformationType(Transformation.TYPE_MATRIX);

    if (childCenter == mCoveflowCenter) {
        transformImageBitmap((ImageView) child, t, 0);
    } else {
        rotationAngle = (int) (((float) (mCoveflowCenter - childCenter) /                           childWidth) * mMaxRotationAngle);
        if (Math.abs(rotationAngle) > mMaxRotationAngle) {
            rotationAngle = (rotationAngle < 0) ? -mMaxRotationAngle
                    : mMaxRotationAngle;
        }
        transformImageBitmap((ImageView) child, t, rotationAngle);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 6):

Did you try calling **invalidate** in the `getChildStaticTransformation()` method like `child.invalidate();`? Every time you want to update a child's static transform, you need to call invalidate() on respective child. If you still have problems in moving through images while clicking on the buttons, you can follow this great [example](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/android-gallery-widget-example-and-tutorial/), So that you would get basic idea on how to go through images with button clicks. If you could post your code snippets where actually it is going wrong, there could be chances of having my answer edited. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have used a constructor and in that i have used  this.setStaticTransformationsEnabled(true).So when ever I drag the screen the method getChildStaticTransformation() is getting fired and the images will displace.But now I want the method to be called in button onTouch event.child.invalidate() did not help

Comment: Can you edit your question with your code? So that it would be easy to answer.

Comment: I have edited the question with code.Please let me know if you get any solution.

Comment: I have found the solution.I just needed to use onFling method.It solved the issue.

Comment: Till now, it didn't get solved? Anyways glad you got the solution. BTW you can answer your question for yourself and mark it as an answer, so that it would be helpful for others who got stuck at the same point.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.I used OnFling Method().

Comment: Hi, It's not sufficient I guess. Just copy paste your code if you can't type answer. lol.. ;) BTW mark your answer. Giving +1 for your question.